# How to sign PDF from Java EE with one USB encryption key?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cryptography, gemalto

currently I work on POC with Java EE in order to sign a PDF with the Gemalto key (the configuration on the key exchange between the web application and the USB already been made)

Actions are:

The user connects to the web application with a USB stick like Gemalto. Once the user is authenticated, he can view a PDF and  click on the button "sign the PDF".

I've got some questions:

- It's possible to get a token or the ID of the USB key of Gemalto ?
- It's possible to get the private key that is stored on the USB key ?
- Each users have got a USB key of Gemalto and how identify a user by the USB key ?

note: If the user does not have USB , it can not be authenticated on the web application.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

A plain web application can not access an USB device for signing a PDF.
For authentication it may be possible if the authentication USB stick has a plugin that is integrated into the user's web browser.

For signing a PDF the only way is currently using the Java plugin in the client browser. However nearly all browsers have already or will disable the NPAPI required for using the Java plugin in the browser. Therefore the Java plugin is a dead horse - don't try to ride it...

May be in some years the proposed [WebUSB API](https://wicg.github.io/webusb/) may be usable in such a case.